# Relative element not wrapping absolute containers

Tags: html, css

I am trying to wrap absolute element in relative wrapper. However after initial try I found that in case relative wrapper does not have any element then explicit height needed to be mentioned for it to wrap absolute elements inside.

I gave it try couldn't solve it. So finally thought good to ask.

```
<style>
.relative{
  background:#ddd;
  position:relative;
  padding:10px; 
}

.front{
  background:red;
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
}

.back{
  background:yellow;
  position:absolute;
  top:0px

}
</style>
<div class="relative">
  <div class="front">
  <h1>Front</h1>
  <p>This is the front side of the element and more fun is still to come</p>
  </div>
  <div class="back">
    <h1>Back</h1>
    <p>This is the back side of the element</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Above is the code and following is link for the [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/anilnamde/pen/saHxo)

However in case mentioning height is only solution then I might be doing wrong markup. Waiting for answers.

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367847/why-doesnt-the-wrapper-div-wrap-the-one-and-two-divs-in-firefox-browser

Comment: @user2211216 i don't think the answer outline the relative absolute positioning its about flow which can be fixed with the overflow:hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Elements with absolute positioning are taken out of inline flow. You must use inline positioning for wrapped element to achieve your goals or use more compex wrapping hierarchy.